# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '@p0'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, dbcontext

I have an exception for the follow code, which seem fine to me, but just don't know why it throws an exception like this. And what does it mean

> 'Incorrect syntax near '@p0'.'

```
public static void ClearData(StoreContext context)
    {
        ExecuteDeleteSQL(context, "Categories");
        ExecuteDeleteSQL(context, "Customers");
        ResetIdentity(context);
    }

public static void ExecuteDeleteSQL(StoreContext context, string tableName)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"Delete from BrooksStore.{tableName}");
    }

public static void ResetIdentity(StoreContext context)
    {
        var tables = new[] { "Categories", "Customers", "OrderDetails", "Orders", "Products", "ShoppingCartRecords" };
        foreach (var itm in tables)
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"DBCC CHECKIDENT (\"BrooksStore.{itm}\", RESEED, -1);");
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you need more information about my project.
Can anyone help me out? Many thanks.

Comment: Your exception is a very generic exception thrown by SQL. There can be many reasons for it.

Comment: It seems because of the table name is not provided after the schema name. @p0 seems to be the parameter name you are trying to pass, but it fails. Try to execute the code with a static text there if it works focus on parameterizing the SQLCommand

Comment: Hi @Eralper. when I hovered my mouse over the tableName VS did showed the name of the variable, which is Categories. I also checked it in the Watch1 window. The value for tableName is Categories in string type. Do you think variable had passed into tableName? And how do you execute code with a static text? many thanks.

Comment: I think @Khalil provided the answer

Comment: Hi @Eralper. I am not sure how Khalil provided me with an answer. I have checked it again, the value from the method did pass into to tableName. I believe the problem is DbContext just can't find the BrooksStore.@p0, which is BrooksStore.Categories. When I went to my SQL Server to select top 10 row of the table, It showed me that it selected from table [BrooksStore].[BrooksStore].[Categories]. The second part, [BrooksStore], is Schema. Any idea what may be wrong in this picture? many thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume you're using EF Core 2, since that's where I encountered the same issue and it is identified as a breaking change for EFCore2.

The issue is that EFCore is trying to convert your string interpolation into a parametrized query, which is not allowed in that specific case.

Simple solution: Cast your interpolated string to a string.

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand((string)$"Delete from BrooksStore.{tableName}");
```

More details can be found here:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9734

> When we updated EF Core to use string interpolation to do
>   parameterization we recognized this as a breaking change for code that
>   was already using it to do things other than parameterization. The
>   guidance going forward is to not let EF do it's parameterization in
>   this case, possibly by casting to string like you show. However, be
>   careful that this does not open your code to SQL injection attacks by
>   making sure that all data is correctly escaped, especially when coming
>   from user input.

Comment: Lifesaver. This was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

I try this. 
It works. You should check other things.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (HYBRIDM5_MeyerEntities context=new HYBRIDM5_MeyerEntities())
            {
                ExecuteDeleteSQL(context, "Sicil");
            }
        }

        public static void ExecuteDeleteSQL(HYBRIDM5_MeyerEntities context, string tableName)
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"Delete from dbo.{tableName}");
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Basar Kaya    the method I try to execute is following: public static void ClearData(StoreContext context)
        {
            ExecuteDeleteSQL(context, "Categories");
            ExecuteDeleteSQL(context, "Customers");
            ResetIdentity(context);
        }

        public static void ExecuteDeleteSQL(StoreContext context, string tableName)
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"Delete from BrooksStore.{tableName}");
        }    I Wrapped ExecuteDeleteSQL() method using using(). It still didn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It should be like this

```
public static void ExecuteDeleteSQL(StoreContext context, string tableName)
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"Delete from BrooksStore.{" + tableName + "}");
}
```

you have to use the **tableName** sent from the message caller

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I tried your method. It didn't work because variable, Categories, didn't even pass into the tableName.

Comment: What? OP's code is passing value of `tableName` in string query. The `$` in the starting means that value will be populated from `tableName`. There is no difference between your answer and OP answer. -1 from me.